# How to read numrical value from a data file in c++ with comments (like Fortran)

Tags: c++, ifstream

I want to read the value of some parameters from a data file. But the data file contains comments after each line starting with ! (it may be symbols like #, //). How to do this with a program like the following,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("input.data");
    int V1;
    double p,q,r,s;
    inFile>>V1>>p>>q>>r>>s;
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

and the data file is this *input.data*

```
5000 0.25   64       !comments here
0.3           !comments here
78.025                !comments here
```

or

```
5000 0.25   64                 !comments here
0.3                            !comments here
78.025                         !comments here
```

Answer (score 3):

You can discard the rest of the lines after reading the numbers that appear on those lines.

```
std::string ignored;
inFile >> V1 >> p >> q;
std::getline(inFile, ignored);
inFile >> r;
std::getline(inFile, ignored);
inFile >> s;
```

Comment: Is there any way that, the input will be taken from a specific length, i.e. in each line the input will be taken from first 200 (suppose) character, the rest will be ignored?

Comment: You still have to go past the characters you are ignoring to know where the next line is.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer slice things to smaller pieces:

```cpp
using LineData = std::vector<double>;
using Data = std::vector<LineData>;

LineData load_line_data(std::istream& input)
{
    LineData result;

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<double>{}, {}, std::back_inserter(result));

    return result;
}

Data load_data(std::istream& input)
{
    Data result;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(input, line)) {
        std::istring_stream line_stream{ line };
        result.push_back(load_line_data(line_stream));
    }
    return result;
}

Data load_data(const std::string& fileName)
{
    std::ifstream f{fileName};
    return load_data(f);
}
```

Data format is not explained well so this is a general solution.

With precise specification: what is in each line, this can be done in different way.

Comment: I'd be tempted to flatten in `load_data`. The first value is an `int`, which *might* be lossy converting from double.

Comment: that is why I've added last line about `precise specification`. `V1`, `p`,  `q`, `r`, `s` names are not informative without context (probably with context it sucks too).